# Vulkan equivalent of IDXGIFactory6::EnumAdapterByGpuPreference?

Tags: vulkan, directx-12

Dx12 has this handy [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/nf-dxgi1_6-idxgifactory6-enumadapterbygpupreference) that I really like and use in my dx12 code.

Does Vulkan have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan's API expects that you can query the various device properties and define a sort order based on whatever properties you prefer. If you want to write such a thing, it wouldn't be too hard, but the API isn't going to provide it for you.

Comment: I'm not saying it's hard to write such a function. I wrote a temporary one that I'm currently using.

Just that the DirectX12 GPUPreference function covers the most common use cases, and I thought Vulkan might have it since it helps get rid of boilerplate code. Vulkan already has a lot of boilerplate.